# Where am I going wrong with converting this code so it does not put the variable in an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

This following snippet of code:

```
if let dict = json?["Stats"] as? [String:AnyObject] {

       if let newdict = dict["biggestWin"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
       self.bigWinPlayer1Goals = newdict.flatMap { $0["player1_goals"] as! String!}
        print (self.bigWinPlayer1Goals)
}
```

outputs:

> ["1"]

However, that `1` is contained within an array - this I do not want.  So I have re-written the code to this:

```
if let newdict = dict["biggestWin"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
        let bigWinPlayer1Goals = newdict ["player1_goals"] as? String
        print (bigWinPlayer1Goals!)
 }
```

However this does not work, and does not output anything.

Where am I going wrong?

This is the array in question:

```
["Stats": {
biggestWin =     (
            {
        "player1_goals" = 1;
        "player2_goals" = 2;
    }
);
goalDifference = "-17";
goalsConceded = 32;
goalsScored = 15;
totalDraws = 3;
totalLosses = 10;
totalWins = 1;
winPercentage = "7.14%";
}]
```

I would like to be able to store `player1_goals` and `player2_goals` in two separate variables.

Comment: Please post the used data and what your expected output should look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned by `dict["biggestWin"]`is of type [String : AnyObject]], i.e. an `Array`of `AnyObject`s.

```
if let data = dict["biggestWin"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
    let newdict = data.first!
    let bigWinPlayer1Goals = newdict ["player1_goals"] as? String
    print (bigWinPlayer1Goals!)
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.  So I was missing the .first command.  What exactly does this do then?  (apart from fix my code!) Just return the first in an array?

Comment: Returning an `Optinal`containing the first element of the array if exists, or nil otherwize. https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array